# How to pass a 10 bit value to two registers?

Tags: c, pic, mplab, xc8

I'm trying to pass the value of `DC` to both `CCPR1L`, `DC1B1`, and `DC1B0`, right now I am doing it manually, but is there a way of using the value of `DC` directly?

```
void SetDCPWM1(unsigned int DC){
    CCPR1L = 0b01011010;
    DC1B1 = 0;
    DC1B0 = 0;
}
```

Right now Im not using `DC` , because I dont know how to correctly pass the value to the registers. `DC` is a 10 bit value , `DC1B1` and `DC1B0` must have bits 1 and 2 and `CCPR1L` must have bits 3 - 10.

Comment: @usr2564301 `because I dont know how to correctly pass the value to the registers`

Comment: You say *right now I am doing it manually*, but your code makes no effort to do so.

Comment: Maybe if you drop the icky bit-fields, all your problem would go away? As you would be able to write a 16 bit word to whatever this underlying register is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the 10-bits of the PWM duty cycle are the low 10-bits of the function parameter then this should do what you have asked for.

```
void SetDCPWM1(unsigned int DC){
    CCPR1L = (DC >> 2);
    DC1B1 = 0;
    DC1B0 = 0;
    if (DC & 2) DC1B1 = 1;
    if (DC & 1) DC1B0 = 1;
}
```

This code should address the comment from Mike :

```
void SetDCPWM1(unsigned int DC){
    CCP1CONbits.DC1B = (unsigned char)(DC) & 0x03;
    CCPR1L = (unsigned char)(DC>>2);
}
```

Further the two LSBs of the PWM duty cycle are now updated in the same instruction cycle.

Comment: Your function could cause small spikes on your output. You bring the two lower bits everytime to zero and than update with new value. In some applications this could be disturbing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void SetDCPWM1(unsigned int DC){
    CCPR1L = (DC >> 2);
    DC1B1  = (DC & 0x0002) ? 1: 0;
    DC1B0  = (DC & 0x0001) ? 1: 0;
}
```

Comment: I used you code and it works fine , but would you mind explaining me a little bit this : `DC1B1  = (DC & 0x0002) ? 1: 0;
    DC1B0  = (DC & 0x0001) ? 1: 0;` I dont fully understand it

Comment: Perhaps the Original Poster found the syntax in my updated answer more straightforward.